# facing permission denied error while accepting mq license

Tags: ibm-mq

We are trying to install MQclient 7.5 on Linux. When we trying to run the following command:

```
./mqlicense.sh -accept
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
ERROR: ./mqlicense.sh ./lap/jre/jre/bin/java:o4o3-006execute permission denied 

ERROR: Installation will not succeed unless the license
agreement can be accepted.

If the error was caused by a display problem,
read the license agreement file (LA_xx, where
xx represents your language ) in the 'licenses'
directory, and then run the following command:

mqlicense.sh -accept

Only use this command if you accept the license
agreement.

For other errors, contact your IBM support centre.
```

Can anyone figure me out what's the problem I am facing and could you tell me the solution

thanks Josh issue got resolved.

actually we are using AIX operating system,and we have downloaded linux binaries so that is the issue it not accepting the license,we removed the linux mq binaries and downloaded AIX binaries,installation done successfully.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l ./lap/jre/jre/bin/java`, what is the output of `sestatus`?

Comment: Are you running it as root?

Comment: What was the  resolution?

Comment: @praveen You are not alone - in the end, the mqlicense.sh script was fixed so from v8 it actually gives you a suitable error message for people that did this :-)